# How to use nested conditions for displaying a hidden block using angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-show

I am trying to put conditions for displaying a hidden div. I  want that after entering some value in 'name' textbox and if we click on search link then the hidden block should appear. But in my code, if we click on search link first then enter any value in textbox then also the hidden div is appearing. But I need that only after entering value in textbox , if we click on search then only hidden div should appear. 
Iam using below code for hiding the div-

```
<div ng-show="name.length>0 && IsVisible">
```

and in script I am writing this code-

```
  $scope.isVisible = false;

   $scope.ShowHide = function () {


                //If DIV is hidden it will be visible and vice versa.
               $scope.IsVisible = true;
            }
```

I have created a plunker here-

https://plnkr.co/edit/oVwZONrn4gtQs1BaiMbO?p=preview

Can any one help me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a condition in the method `ShowHide` itself:

```
$scope.ShowHide = function () {
    if($scope.name) {
        //If DIV is hidden it will be visible and vice versa.
        $scope.IsVisible = true;
    }
}
```

If you wish the *hidden* section to be visible only when '*Search*' is clicked, then make changes as per following in the HTML file:

```
<div ng-show="IsVisible">
```

Refer to the demo [**here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0Q9ni3xEqBaMWiW2RAZq?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/PX976lUgM7wfeDIkYO0H?p=preview). Added a watch on name change:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-change="resetShowHide()" ng-class="" ng-model="name" required/>
```

and if the name length is 0, reset is IsVisible

```
  $scope.resetShowHide = function(){
    if($scope.name.length) $scope.IsVisible = false;
  }
```